# Credit card at Best Buy

Tags: united-states, credit-card

I also just bought a TV worth $1400 with a best buy credit card. I only want to pay for the TV and never use this card again. Can someone tell me what I should do after I pay for my TV? How will not using this card affect my credit score?

Comment: Also? What else? It feels like I walked into the middle of a conversation.

Answer (score 1):

According to myfico, having an open credit card with an available balance will raise your credit score. This happens because if the card is paid off that will increase your overall available credit. However if you do not use your card then the issuer will most likely close the account automatically after usually about 1 year of inactivity. As long as they are not charging you, an annual fee then it will help your score by charging something annually then paying it off as your length of credit history will grow.